# Unable to load data into hive table in correct format

Tags: hadoop, hive

I am trying to load the below table which is having two array typed columns in hive.

Base table:

```
Array<int> col1   Array<string> col2
[1,2]             ['a','b','c']
[3,4]             ['d','e','f']
```

I have created the table in hive as below:

```
create table base(col1 array<int>,col2 array<string>) row format delimited fields terminated by '\t' collection items terminated by ',';
```

And then loaded the data as below:

```
load data local inpath '/home/hduser/Desktop/batch/hiveip/basetable' into table base;
```

I have used below command:

```
select * from base;
```

I got the output as below

```
 [null,null]     ["['a'","'b'","'c']"]
 [null,null]     ["['d'","'e'","'f]"]
```

I am not getting the data in correct format.

Please help me out where I am getting wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can change the **datatype** of **col1 array** of **string** instead on array of int then you can get the data for col1.

***With col1 datatype as Array(string):-***

```
hive>create table base(col1 array<string>,col2 array<string>) row format delimited fields terminated by '\t' collection items terminated by ',';
hive>select * from base;
+--------------+------------------------+--+
|     col1     |          col2          |
+--------------+------------------------+--+
| ["[1","2]"]  | ["['a'","'b'","'c']"]  |
| ["[3","4]"]  | ["['d'","'e'","'f']"]  |
+--------------+------------------------+--+
```

Why is this behaviour because hive not able to detect the values inside array as integers as we are having 1,2 values enclosed in **[]**
***Accessing col1 elements:-***

```
   hive>select col1[0],col1[1] from base;
    +------+------+--+
    | _c0  | _c1  |
    +------+------+--+
    | [1   | 2]   |
    | [3   | 4]   |
    +------+------+--+
```

**(or)**

***With col1 datatype as Array(int type):-***

if you are thinking to don't want to change the datatype then you need to keep your input file as below **without [] square brackets** for **array**(i.e.col1) values.

```
1,2     ['a','b','c']
3,4     ['d','e','f']
```

then create table same as you mentioned in the question, then hive can detect the first 1,2 as array elements as int type.

```
hive> create table base(col1 array<int>,col2 array<string>) row format delimited fields terminated by '\t' collection items terminated by ',';

hive> select * from base;
+--------+------------------------+--+
|  col1  |          col2          |
+--------+------------------------+--+
| [1,2]  | ["['a'","'b'","'c']"]  |
| [3,4]  | ["['d'","'e'","'f']"]  |
+--------+------------------------+--+
```

***Accessing array elements:-***

```
   hive> select col1[0] from base;
    +------+--+
    | _c0  |
    +------+--+
    | 1    |
    | 3    |
    +------+--+
```